# Can someone request to a Judge in your country to give a letter of appreciation for appearing as a witness?

Tags: germany, citizenship, reference-request

Say a person X appeared as a witness in a case where the judge was presiding in a criminal case (Jugendstrafsache). The testimony of X was welcomed and appreciated highly by the prosecutor as well as the judge.

X is not an EU citizen. X wants German citizenship under "special integration" circumstances. Can X request the judge to write/sign a draft letter that states that X has acted in a manner as would be expected of a German citizen?

Broader question: Are people allowed to write to the judiciary for any such relevant requests at all?

Comment: Wait, what? Are you referring to [§ 10 ⑶ 2 StAG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stag/englisch_stag.html#p0063) “civic involvement”? This really refers to _prolonged_ (≥ 2 years) activities with some _integrating_ character, e. g. membership in a refugee organization or so.

Comment: No, I am not referring to that. I want to strengthen  § 10 ⑶ 2 StAG with other supporting documents.

Comment: That part refers to ***outstanding** efforts at integration,* - merely doing your civic duties is generally not outstanding, but special cases might make it special - so ask your immigration officer.

Comment: 'Outstanding' is open to interpretation and has been contended, c.f. https://openjur.de/u/854298.html but your point is valid.

Comment: The plaintiff in that case did show his integration by volunteering in a political party, organized an art exhibition and helped in another. Those are not duties one has to do like paying taxes or appearing ats a witness.

Comment: Yes, and the immigration officer was clearly not satisfied with all that, that is why the court had to be approached.

Comment: The problem is, _appearing_ as a witness does _not_ show signs of _efforts_ at _integrating_ yourself _into_ German society. It’s not like you _caused_ the crime to happen, you know what I mean? The shortening of the qualification period is granted _because_ you’ve shown quite an “investment” into living in Germany. _This_ is honored. I reckon obliging with the local laws is quite a feat, but, as Trish said, it ain’t “special” but _mandatory_ (cf. possible exclusion/revocation grounds, §§ 5 Ⅰ, 11, 12a, 35 StAG).

Comment: Yes, that point has been clarified. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is the duty of the witness to give the testimony, no matter what their nationality is. As a witness, a German citizen is not different from a French, Uruguayan, or even a stateless.

The only letter the judge will usually give them in addition to a verbal thanks is a formal letter recognizing that they have, on suchandsuch day(s), been called as a witness to the court and appeared. This is usually given to any witness and pretty much a form. It does serve as evidence for example in cases of absence from work - and [you are entitled to the losses you incurred for appearing in court if you formally request them.](https://oberlandesgericht-braunschweig.niedersachsen.de/startseite/z_ablage_alte_knotenpunkte/hinweise_fur_zeugen/rechte-und-pflichten-des-zeugen-vor-gericht-148276.html)

It isn't forbidden to request a different letter from a judge, but they might not give such an extraordinary letter of appreciation, because that might taint the case: it could raise the question if the testimony was bought with or made to gain such a letter.

Comment: Thanks. What if the request is made a significant time after the testimony? What could be other reasons to decline?

Comment: You should ask your immigration officer or lawyer what you need and if that is something the court can or will provide.